# RemotingConfiguration lock my file, how to use log4net's RemotingAppender?

Tags: c#, log4net, remoting

## client.cs

```
    RemotingAppender remotingAppender = new RemotingAppender();
    remotingAppender.Sink = "tcp://localhost:15642/LoggingSinkInConsoleDaemon";
    remotingAppender.BufferSize = 1;
    remotingAppender.ActivateOptions();
    BasicConfigurator.Configure(remotingAppender);
    log.Info("everything is ok!");
```

## server.cs

```
    LogManager.GetRepository().PluginMap.Add(new Plugin.RemoteLoggingServerPlugin("LoggingSinkInConsoleDaemon"));
```

client.exe log to server.exe, everything is ok, and after client.exe exit, i use Unlocker.exe(which can be found [here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/)) find that client.exe is locked by server.exe(which means i can't delete client.exe yet because it is used by server.exe), i locate the error which is caused by RemotingAppender, but i don't know how to resolve.

i think Remoting handle the RemotingAppender's request, and it have locked client.exe, how can i release the lock?

======================update 1===================================

client.cs

```
    var repo = LogManager.GetRepository();
    var app = repo.GetAppenders().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(RemotingAppender)).FirstOrDefault();
    var remotingAppender = app as RemotingAppender;

    var root = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
    var attachable = root as IAppenderAttachable;
    attachable.RemoveAppender(remotingAppender);
```

i tried above it works, but i lose my log.

i search the source, RemoveAppender remove the logger from list, so it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at all but have you tried remotingAppender.Close(); when you finish with it ?

Comment: and LogManager.Shutdown() ?